# How to define the initialState correct for a react component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

For example, an ArticleList component, at first, there is no data;

the state maybe something like:

```js
state = {
  articleList: [],
  isFetching: false
}
```

At first, i want it to render to nothing(null).

If i check the isFetching is true, then render null.But it will also render a loading spinner base on that isFetching state.

If i check the articleList.length === 0, then render null. But it also want to display some user friendly message base on that state.

So if there should be some other property to determine that the initial render result is null?

Is there any best practise to this situation?

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
   this.state = {};
to initialise the state

you must then use this.setState() as described in the documentation.

in es6 you can use

```
variable === undefined
```

and

```
variable === null
```

to check the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
state = {
   articleList : [],
   fetching: false
}
render() {
   const {fetching, articleList} = this.state;
   if(fetching) {
       //show loader here
      return loader;
   }
   if(!fetching && articleList) {
      if(articleList.length === 0) {
       //show message here
       return message;
      }
      //render content here
      return content;
   }
   return null;
}
```